# How to upgrade pidgin

Tags: software-installation, pidgin

I've just installed `pidgin` in `Ubuntu` and even done `$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install pidgin`. However, when I check its version, it is still `2.10.9`. And this version has some problems, which were solved only in version `2.10.10`. So, I want to upgrade, but I do not know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that only 2.10.9 is available in the Ubuntu repos.  You can check which version is available with the command `apt-cache policy pidgin`. Here's what I get when I run that command on Ubuntu 15.04:

> dagrha@laptop:~$ apt-cache policy pidgin
>
> pidgin:   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 1:2.10.9-0ubuntu8
>   Version table:
>        1:2.10.9-0ubuntu8 0
>           500 [http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages](http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/)

So you can see, 2.10.9 is the latest that is available through the Ubuntu repos.

If you want the newest version you'll probably have to install from source: https://www.pidgin.im/download/source/.  That website will have a readme or set of instructions for how to install from source.

Comment: I downloaded the source code, unzipped it. But when I do `$ make` inside the folder with all the source code, I get `make: *** No targets specified ...`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There should be a file called INSTALL in that archive you downloaded.  Sorry, don't mean to be daft, but are doing exactly what it says?

Comment: it's ok. you are right. in fact, i missed one step. Thanks!